# Subscript Options in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a tutorial from which I was studying Swift & about Subscript Options. The below is a simple code of documentation's example on this topic.

```
struct Matrix {
    let rows: Int, columns: Int
    var print: [Double]
    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        print = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    }
    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Double {
        get {
            return print[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            print[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
var mat = Matrix(rows: 3, columns: 3)

mat[0,0] = 1.0
mat[0,1] = 2.0
mat[1,0] = 3.0
mat[1,1] = 5.0

println("\(mat[0,0])")
println("\(mat[0,1])")
println("\(mat[1,0])")
println("\(mat[1,1])")
```

Can any one please explain me what is going on here. I am unable to make out about Subscript Options from this example. And might be there would be many like me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: subscript is shorthand mathod for calling function and accessing members. Same you doing in code by calling subscript using `[]` brackets.

Comment: *Remark:* `print` is a "built-in" Swift function. Using the same name for a property `var print: [Double]` is possible, but can easily lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Subscripts enable you to query instances of a type by writing one or
>   more values in square brackets after the instance name. Their syntax
>   is similar to both instance method syntax and computed property
>   syntax. You write subscript definitions with the subscript keyword,
>   and specify one or more input parameters and a return type, in the
>   same way as instance methods. Unlike instance methods, subscripts can
>   be read-write or read-only. This behavior is communicated by a getter
>   and setter in the same way as for computed properties

I think that Apple [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html) is quit good.

If you like Ray Wenderlich - see [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79764/custom-subscripting-swift-tutorial).